# Javascript split ain't working on iPad (safari)

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari

Javascript ain't working for me ;-(

```
function myFunction() {

var url = document.getElementById("value1").value;

document.write(url.split('?')[0]);

window.location = 'http://example.com/?s='+ url.split('?')[0];
 }
```

value1 = https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/nl/p/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy/9200000056577975/?suggestionType=browse

i only need the stuff before the questionmark (https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/nl/p/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy/9200000056577975/)

it is working on PC (IE, Opera,...), but it ain't on iPad (safari)
I get this on ipad: https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/nl/p/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy/9200000056577975/suggestionType=browse

What is wrong?

update:
I have added some code:

```
function myFunction() {

var url = document.getElementById("value1").value;



document.write(url.split('?')[0]);

url = url.replace(/%2F/g,'/');
url = url.replace(/%3A/g,'/');
url = url.replace(/%3F/g,'?');

window.location = 'http://example.com/?s=' + url.split('?')[0];
 }
```

it is working but safari is screwing up the urls that are added. Input box is used for urls. on PC all working as it should. the .replace are used to try edit the submitted urls but ain't working. Safari document.write still shows the right urls without the %2F and %3A .

Comment: @Kornflexx it is a string.... if it is type text

Comment: Have you tried replacing document.write() ? Do you get the url correctly on ipad?

Comment: the `document.write(url.split('?')[0]);` shows  https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/nl/p/yyyyyyyyyyyyyy/9200000056577975/,suggestionType=browse And replacing it with `document.write(url)` it shows the correct url including the questionmark. But redirect goes to ...../suggestionType=browse

Comment: `` var url = document.getElementById("value1").value.toString();`` Also no changes

Comment: correction: `document.write(url.split('?')[0]);` now show the right url. without the stuff after the questionmark + questionmark. Strange the redirect aint working correct

Comment: You will need to encode everything after the ? in the url before setting the window location.

Comment: Seems to be working correctly for me... http://donmag.com/a/jssplit.html

Comment: Great! you are the best. Works fine now :-)